# Shift an array by n-positions in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

Is there a nice way to shift an array in Lightning Components?

I'm using this array in aura:iteration, so, I was thinking of using start/end attributes. Unfortunately it doesn't shift and just offsets the array.

Or perhaps I am missing some combinator (start=5, end=5)?

```
<aura:iteration items=[1,2,3,4] var="1">
    {!i}
</aura:iteration>
```

When n = 2, should render

```
3,4,1,2
```

Comment: can you add your code as well

Comment: @Himanshu added

Comment: There are no standard way to achieve what you are looking for. Best possible solution would be to update the list as per your requirement in your action callback (Where you retrieve the list from server).

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You'd have to modify the array in the actual variable being stored. Since it's all client-side memory, it'd be pretty cheap to build the data however you'd like. Unfortunately, there is neither a "rows" nor "offset" attribute as there is in Visualforce.